# saving record with active admin on heroku not works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

I'm using `active_admin` in my rails app. When I try to add a new record for the `PostCategory` model, it doesn't work.

I can add the other models on Heroku but only `PostCategory` doesn't work. 
On my local machine all models can be added, including `PostCategory`.

Sometimes the log file says 500 internal error.

My heroku logs:

```
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946410+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946411+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:111:in `run_validations!'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946413+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:317:in `valid?'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946414+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:70:in `valid?'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946416+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946464+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946418+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946435+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:267:in `save'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946437+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:160:in `block in save_resource'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946439+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:45:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946440+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:45:in `public_send'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946441+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:45:in `try'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946446+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/callbacks.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in define_active_admin_callbacks'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946470+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946448+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:159:in `save_resource'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946472+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946422+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946450+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-ad33a0f6c772/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:149:in `block in create_resource'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946474+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946475+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946476+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946478+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946463+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946461+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946466+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946467+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946468+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946471+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946479+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946480+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946484+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946482+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946487+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946489+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946483+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946486+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946493+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946490+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946492+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946495+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946511+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946512+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946514+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946515+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946507+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946496+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946500+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946502+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946505+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946508+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946510+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionview-4.1.0/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946517+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946518+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946520+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946521+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946523+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946524+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946525+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946527+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946528+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946530+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946532+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946533+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946534+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946536+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946537+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946549+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946539+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946540+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946542+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946543+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946545+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946546+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946548+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946550+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946551+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946554+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946556+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946557+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946562+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946586+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946590+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946589+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946591+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946593+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946594+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946595+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946597+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946599+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946600+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946602+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946603+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946605+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946606+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946618+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-05-25T17:27:30.946619+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Gem File

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

gem 'devise'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

gem 'pg', group: :production

gem 'debugger'

gem 'pry', group: :development
```

post_category.rb :

```
ActiveAdmin.register PostCategory do
  permit_params :title

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :title
    column :created_at
    column :slug_url

    actions
  end

  filter :created_at


  form do |f|
    f.inputs "PostCategory Details" do
      f.input :title
    end
    f.actions
  end

    controller do
        defaults :finder => :find_by_slug_url
    end

end
```

see PostCategory on heroku console

```
PostCategory(id: integer, title: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, slug_url: string)
```

PostCategory model :

```
class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_uniqueness_of :slug_url
    before_save :before_save

    private
    def before_save
        self.slug_url = self.title.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '')
    end

    public 
    def to_param  # overridden
        slug_url
    end
end
```

Comment: hard to say but it looks like validation error if you can to paste the form and the model will be easier to detect the problem, any way check out your validations and the input maybe you miss something.

Comment: I added post_category controller. adding just tittle filed.

Comment: what about `slug_url` does it has any validation? show me the model also

Comment: yes it was about validation.. thank you matanco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have multi problems:

1. change `def before_save` into something else this is rails method don't use the same name also make a validation that title is not empty/nil(present?) before try use downcase on it otherwise you will get error (undefined method downcase for nil:nilClass)
2. i think that the first time you tried it works if you will query you will see that your database contain 1 record if you will try submit it again it will not work due to your validation `validates_uniqueness_of :slug_url`